# What is the return value of `$<-` function?

Tags: r

I am reimplementing the `$<-` function, but the documentation is not clear or explicit on what the function is supposed to return. The implementation is just calling .Primitive, but this is also dependent on the internal implementation of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should return an "updated" copy of the object. For example you could do something crazy like this (here wrapped in `local` to not change the default behavior of `$<-`)

```
local({
  `$<-` <- function(x, k, value) {
    action <- deparse(substitute(k))
    if (action == "multiply") {
      x * value
    } else if (action == "add") {
      x + value
    }
  }
  x <- 5
  x$multiply <- 2
  x$add <- 3
  x
})
# [1] 13
```

So if you had code like `x$greeting <- "hello"` then `$<-` should return whatever you want `x` to be after the assignment. That's the value that will be reassigned to `x`

This is loosely described in the [subset assignment](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment) section of the R Language Definition